# Dynamically created script element not executing properly

Tags: javascript, dynamic, element

I have a function that creates a script element and dynamically populates the source URL. The source URL for the script element returns an advertisement (image and text) wrapped in a document.write();.

When I hard code the script element, it works fine. When I use the dynamically created one, which is exactly the same, the document.write(); doesn't execute, but it is there.

I'm just wondering if anyone has a clue what might be causing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.write();` dynamically will erase all content in the document and replace it with the text inside the parameters. It's not recommended you use it as there are better ways of inserting text into the DOM. Namely,[`.appendChild();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild) or at least 
[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML)